# I need to load the distance data from Google Maps and save it to my Database

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

I got 5550 records of different routes and I need to do a foreach loop for each record and get the API data.
So I made a function with Guzzle in Laravel:

```
public function getDirectionDistance($origins, $distinations)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origins&destinations=$distinations&key=ччч")->getBody()->getContents();
    $obj =  json_decode($res, true);
    $distance =  $obj['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $clean = $string = str_replace(' km', '', $distance);
    return $clean;

}
```

I used it in a store method

```
public function store()
{
    $route = $this->route->with('from','to')->get();
    $maps = new Maps();

    foreach ($route as $item){

        $direction = new Direction();
        $from = $item->from->name;
        $to = $item->to->name;
        $direction->route_id = $item->id;
        $direction->distance = $maps->getMapsApi("$from,israel","$to,israel");
        $direction->save();
        sleep(3);

    }

}
```

But when I do It, I get 1 distance for 200 routes and then after 200 row I get the next distance for the next route. How to stop and wait for api to be completed, save it and then start the next row. I need the data to create a Machine Learning price calculator.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to save all 5500 records as once ?

Comment: Yes, I want to save the distance with the route_id and make a relation for the route.

Comment: You can divide data in chunck and save it all data at once, it will divide in small chunck and will save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me work in this way:
I created a function that make a call to google with CURL:

```
public function calculateDistance($origins, $destination){
     $staticDistanceModel = New StaticDistance();
     $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" . $origins . "&destinations=" . $destination . "&mode=driving&language=it-IT&key=xyz";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
            if (isset($response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'])) {
               $m = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
            }else{
               $m = 0;
            }

            $staticDistanceModel->insertStatic($origins, $destination, $m);
        }
    }
```

the function in my model is something like:

```
public function insertStatic($origins, $destination, $m){
        $arrayInsert = array('origins'=>$origins, 'destination'=>$destination,'distance'=>$m);
        Self::create($arrayInsert);
    }
```

And in my controller I have forEach() like this:

```
foreach ($array as $object) {
   $calculator = $this->calculateDistance($object->origins, $object->destination);
}
```

But be careful because google limit request, and the time for 5500 records maybe long, so you can chunk array.

Hope this can help you